# General question about our universe, mathematics and physics: Why is 1+1=2?

Tags: existence, universe

Although everyone is surely wondering about this question, I am asking it here though:

Why is 1+1=2?

Why is our universe build up like in that way, that such a formula is always working? (I know the Newtons basic laws: e.g., Where an "atomical" mass is can not be another at the same time, therefore it has to be: mass + mass = 2 x mass)

Are there other places in our "extistence" (universe etc.), where it can be in another way - even hypothetical? (The - possible - anti matter "world" seems to be working in that way too).

And additionally questioned: Why there are mathematical functions, which have at some point no result (better spoken: ininity?). Are they comparable to, e.g., black holes - or the event horizon?

Could it be that our universe is like mathematical/bounding "box", in which - if we could - reach the e.g. the top end, we get immediately to the bottom, e.g. like the program

move_right: x=x+1; if x> (a_value) then x= 0;

move_left: x=x-1; if x< 0 then x= a_value;

(same for y and z direction)

**Before anyone here is "voting" to close this question as off-topic: I've asked it already in Astronomy, where the people told me to drop it in another forum!**

**Addendum 20170821:** I meant it in special in materialistic way. Why couldn't materia not behave like intense way, although there are enough place betweenin (sub-)atomaric level between the nucleus and the surronding electrosn (otherwise the light quants/waves woulnd't pass eg. glass / H2O molecules etc.)

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. About 1+1=2: does https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/8738/2953, esp. "What [Peano] was attempting to do was find a set of axioms that accurately captures our intuition about how the integers act," answer your question? It's not clear to me what you intend to ask with your second question - why would these functions be "comparable" and in what sense? I also don't see how this question or the third one is related to philosophy as defined in the [help/on-topic]. As for the third question, are you looking for anything more than "Yes, it could, but why would it?"?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I followed the physical way about the question 1+1=2, not the [peano]. The second question I was thinking about that whether there are possible places which don't base on the phsyical formula. The third question (why there are functions which have an  infinite result at some point) I was thinking about posibility that a black hole is like such a function with an inifite result inside it. Of course (but I do not ) could ask physics scientists Stephen Hawking et al. :) about that, but I would like to know whether there are other explanations and ideas about that

Comment: As Einstein said "*As far as the laws of mathematics refer to reality, they are not certain, and as far as they are certain, they do not refer to reality*". This formula is "always working" because it expresses our convention for using symbols 1, 2, + and =, not anything about the universe. For physical things it will not always be working: when we put two droplets of water next to each other they merge, so 1+1=1 in that case. The question of physics is when our made up rules for symbols approximate something real, and the reason they often do is that those that do are just more useful to us.

Comment: First answer: we define **2** as **1+1**; more precisely, we define **2** as **the** *successor* of **1** and we prove that, in general, **n+1** is equal to the successor of **n**.

Comment: Second answer: while the world is as it as ? Because God made it so.

Comment: >>"For physical things it will not always be working: when we put two droplets of water next to each other they merge, so 1+1=1 in that case. T"<<. From visible view you're correct - But the mass of water is doubled. Maybe near light speed?

Comment: But the mass for THAT new water droplet I meant is doubled. And Lightspeed, I think is one of such a border which doesn't (so far we know) fit the law 1+1=2 (Lightspeed +1 m/s ) = LS. But why all other stuff in ourr universe underly that formula?

Comment: There is plenty of "other stuff" that does not, many quantities are intensive, like temperature, adding objects with the same temperatures does not add their temperatures, etc. *Some* stuff obeys it, and it happens to be useful to us, which is why we invented symbols that mimic that. The order of explanation is in reverse.

Comment: It's basically a definition. 2 is defined as the successor of 1, and you can define '+' in such a way that it respects successors; that is, S1 = 1 + 1 = 2. In other words 2 is just the name for the whole number that comes after 1.

Comment: Hmm. It seems to me that the definition of '1' is that two of them make 2. For this reason I'd say the real question is how we get from zero to one, and that once we've done that the rest follows. But I'm out of my comfort zone here.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by 1, what do you mean by 2, and what do you mean by +?

This is really the key question here -- if you're just taking a naive view of numbers as 'objects that count how many things I have' (these are really cardinal numbers), then of course 1+1=2. If I have one object and I then gain another object I have two objects total, and we have picked the symbols 1 and 2 to represent these notions with the symbol + to represent the aquisition of more objects.

But what if we are keeping track of the number of particles in a quantum system? Say we shoot 1 proton at 1 other proton at about 99% of the speed of light -- do we now have 2 protons? Not so! In particle physics we have found that if you produce enough energy to replicate a given particles rest mass and you confine the energy to small enough of an area, the particle can come into existence in exchange for the energy (this is a very rough outline). The particle collider over at CERN takes advantage of this fact to study some of the most fundamental physics in our universe by slamming two protons into each other* with a bunch of extra kinetic energy (hence 99% LS), at which point literally hundreds of new particles are created and tracked using magnetic fields and photomultipliers and many other complicated devices.

So if 1 and 2 and 3 and so on are counting the number of particles we have and + represents putting them together with great force, then 1+1=500 or something like that. We could instead choose to use numbers for keeping track of the scalar quantity we call energy throughout the above process and argue that this number does indeed follow regular addition laws, but then you have specified entirely what you mean by 1 and 2 (and +)! This is really the heart of the answer -- 1+1=2 whenever the quantities you have defined to be 1 and 2 together with the relation + satisfy this equality.

*the protons do not actually collide -- they are forced to within incredibly small distances of eachother, at which point vector bosons can mediate short range interactions between the momentum states of the protons to effectively produce a 'collision'.

Answer (score 0):

Whole volumes could be written about the various attempts, starting with Leibniz and not yet ending with Russell, to prove from the axioms that 1 + 1 = 2. Of course the answer *why* 1 + 1 = 2 will be answered in different ways by the experts of different scientific branches, depending on their points of view. But there is a very simple and, as far as myself and many friends and students are concerned, also very satisfying answer.

Mathematics, first in its basic structures including counting, and the four basic operations, and later in many productively evolving branches, has been shaped by the physical environment. Therefore it is in no way surprising that it describes this environment. Whether you take two apples or two sheep or two equal masses: The result is always twice of the single property. Even in modern mathematics numbers have been identified with cardinalities of sets. Three is the cardinal number of all sets that contain three elements. (It is not allowed to talk about the *set* of all such sets, but we say *class*, and everything is fine.) Three is the number of trees in my garden. And 7*7 = 49 according to the tables which everybody has learnt in school and which they can check with a handful of coins.

Therefore there is absolutely no reason to brood about the unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics in the natural sciences. *Mathematics simply has been constructed that way.* Therefore it is not at all necessary to "prove" that 1 + 1 = 2. And if mathematicians would choose a different axiom system where 1 + 1 = 3 could be proved, then this kind of mathematics would simply become irrelevant for any practical purpose as we can observe it with other theories which are completely decoupled from reality.

Comment: "Whether you take two apples or two sheep or two equal masses: The result is always twice of the single property." This is at best simplified and at worst fundamentally incorrect. Adding speeds doesn't behave like that at all for example. Adding masses doesn't once you consider quantum physics. Saying mathematics was purposefully constructed to describe these things far beyond even our current intuition is also historically incorrect and epistemologically absurd.

Comment: On top of that, 1+1=2 is not axiomatic as you seem to imply, it's a definition (those are not the same thing). Writing "2" literally just means 1+1, or S(1) or whatever you prefer. It's just notation, there is no mathematical knowledge in 1+1=2 which needs to be proven. "2" is just a name for the natural number after 1. "+1" is the operation which assigns to each natural numbers its successor. The *real* question that should be asked here is why do we define N a certain way and not another (and this *is* a fascinating subject, despite you seemingly trying to play it down as inconsequential).

Comment: o + o = oo is not an axiom but a law taken from the reality of bodies in the world. 1 + 1 = 2 is not an axiom but a definition of the meaning of 2 like all statements in the tables from 1*1 = 1 to 10*10 = 100 and beyond. Axioms are sometimes useful but not really necessary in mathematics. Why do we define |N the way we do? The answer is simple: Because everything else would lead to contradictions when being applied. (Your examples with velocities etc, do not belong to this realm - like 1 + 1 = 3 in biological reproduction.)

Comment: You're completely oversimplifying the issue and you're also completely wrong. Non-standard models of arithmetic have been constructed which generate number sets that you'd find very, very alien, yet still work for every single practical application like counting and the trivial addition you've used as your example. The notion that the natural numbers are the only way to get this done simply isn't true. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic .

Comment: *You* are completely wrong. There is no practical application of any part of a non-standard system that differes from the natural numbers. These systems are as useless for mathematics as astrology or vodoo. I will prove that when you tell me what you think is a practical application.

Comment: I didn't say that it has practical applications, I said that your statement that anything other than the typical definition of the natural numbers would lead to contradictions is plain false. That is what I said and it's true. *You* claimed and I quote: "Why do we define |N the way we do? The answer is simple: Because everything else would lead to contradictions when being applied." This is false.

Comment: Now, on top of you having addressed a strawman argument which I never made, it's actually also false that non-standard arithmetic has no applications. Non-standard analysis simplifies some proofs significantly, while making others more difficult. It is unfortunately not a clear-cut case of which is better. It simply isn't. Comparing a totally valid and useful system of model theory with lots of research being put into it to astrology or voodoo is absurd. Literally *every* practical human application of the natural numbers like counting works identically for non-standard arithmetic by the way.

Comment: I suggest you start here (https://math.berkeley.edu/~jhicks/links/SOTS/koneill030514.pdf) or here (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407178) or with any textbook that covers the step from non-standard model theory up until non-standard analysis. It has many proponents all over the world but it also has many people arguing that we don't necessarily need it. You on the other hand are arguing it is contradictory, which is plain isn't and that it has no applications which is also false. Whether those applications are superior to regular arithmetic or not - it still *has* applications either way.

Comment: You claimed "work for every single practical application". But there is nothing useful except the natural part. omega *is* contradictory: It means finished infinity, i.e., nonsense. Of course there are many people in the world who defend this nonsense and believe in "proofs" like Gentzen's or infinite sequences from zero to infinite ordinals but finite sequences from there to zero. But with no doubt more research has been put into astrology than in non-standard models of  numbers and more people are believing in the former than in the latter.

Comment: @TimonG. It's time again for our scheduled warning: "Heinrich" is generally believed to be one of the screen names of Wolfgang Mückenheim, and discussions with Wolfgang Mückenheim are generally believed to be pointless. Others have tried that for years. (Ask Google.)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the fair warning @Uwe. I think I've argued my position sufficiently anyway, anything beyond this point wouldn't fit with the idea behind SE commenting. I have a general rule to not discuss further with people who are unwilling to make a distinction between proper peer reviewed research and repeatedly refuted pseudo-science.

Answer (score 0):

`1 + 1 = 2` is a mathematical statement.  To say it is "always working" in the universe is a bit tricky.  There's a selection bias hidden in that statement.  A more reasonable phrase would be "1+1=2 always works in our universe for topic which we have found it to always work for."  It turns out that we attribute great importance to the facets of the universe where the laws of addition apply, but there's plenty of cases where it doesn't work out that well.

Consider random walks as an example.  In random walks, 1 + 1 does not equal 2.  In fact, if you're doing your random walk in one dimension, there' a 50% chance that the two random walks will be in opposite directions, suggesting `1 + 1 = 0`!.  Random walks happen all the time in nature.  That's why air molecules can collide with each other billions of times every second and generally stay in the same place.

Also, there are gestalt properties.  Gestalt is actually a concept built around 1 + 1 not equaling 2.  The official phrasing for a gestalt is "a system where the sum of the parts is not the same as the whole."  I'm quite certain that you would not be comfortable with me cutting you in half, and arguing that two halves are just as good as the whole was.  It's not a place where you would like to have to argue `1/2 + 1/2 = 1`.

In religions, we very often find marriage phrased as "two flesh become one."  That's certainly not `1 + 1 = 2`.   That's `1 + 1 = 1`!

So really, the universe is full of all sorts of different properties.  Some of them can be modeled using the laws of arithmetic, some cannot.  If you find that the universe "always works" using the laws of addition, then that suggests that your preferred ways of viewing the world select for those laws.

As for your torroidal universe (which is the technical name for your universe in a box), the counter question would be "why couldn't the universe be torroidal?"  What fundamental laws does the universe uphold that would prevent it?  The joy of hypotheticals like that is you never have to prove that the universe *is* torroidal, just that there's nothing preventing it.  As for what it would mean?  It turns out that the laws of physics you use work just fine on a torroid.  They don't require a flat space (which is good, because relativity suggests space is not locally flat!)

Answer (score -2):

Alfred North Whitehead and Bertrand Russell wrote Principia Mathematica wherein they tried to lay out the foundations of mathematics. After years of intensive research, they eventually published it in three volumes in the years 1910-1913.

On page 362, they finally got around to proving that 1 + 1 = 2 :

[image]

Unfortunately there's but a handful of people in the world with both the intelligence and the patience to get to page 362 and be able to understand their conclusion. I'm not one of these people, so I guess I'll just have to take their word for it! Maybe you can figure it out now you know where to find it?

Anyway, I did read [**Logicomix**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1596914521), which is a graphic novel that describes Russell's pursuit for knowledge... including his work on the Principia Mathematica. I highly recommend it for anyone who wants to learn more about the history of the [**philosophy of mathematics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics)... who wants to learn more about Bertrand Russel's contributions in particular... or who wants to get a better understanding of why it's nearly impossible to prove something as fundamental as 1 + 1 = 2.

Comment: This answer doesn't really server to answer the question. All you've done is state that Russell and Whitehead attempted to create a foundational system in PM and they give a proof of 1+1=2, but you don't attempt to explain their proof, explain the nature of PM or type theory, explain who they are, or explain any of the details related to what you've posted. The OP asked "why does 1+1=2?" and all you've done is say that two people answered that question but you personally find their answer confusing.

Comment: @Not_Here :  I posted a screenshot of page 362 with the conclusion of why 1 + 1 = 2. As I said, there's unfortunately but a handful of people in the world who actually understands it... and I'm not one of them. So I've done the best I could here. If you are one of those few people who does understand their reasoning and their conclusions, feel free to explain them. Either way, it's not because I don't understand it that I reject their conclusion. This is one of those very rare cases where I'm willing to take someone's word for it ;-)

Comment: Not sure a graphic like that helps anything whatsoever.

Comment: @jeffreysbrother : Well... `"I do not know if Russell and Whitehead intended Principia Mathematica to be readable by humans—but in the end Russell estimated years later that only perhaps 6 people had ever read the whole thing."` — [**source**](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2010/11/100-years-since-principia-mathematica/)

Comment: PM is not as complicated as it seems, given your rep on SO you probably have at least a competent understanding of type theory, even if you don't realize it. Can you understand any basic lisp or better yet scheme? But that is all beside the point, it is not "damn near impossible" to prove that 1+1=2, its trivially done in PA or ZFC. My point is that this answer doesn't answer what the OP asked, all it does is say you don't understand something someone a long time ago wrote. And im pretty sure jeffreysbrother was referring to how pixilated the image you posted is.

Comment: You don't have to read every single page of PM to understand it or to learn about type theory, most CS undergrads could handle everything in that book if it was written with modern symbols and they paid attention in discrete math class. The fact that your answer just claims that they had a proof but its too esoteric to understand so oh well maybe someone else can understand it is really just driving home the point that it isn't a useful answer at all.

Comment: @Not_Here : `"But in Principia Mathematica, instead of being given English-based names, all these objects are assigned special notations. The first handful are not too difficult to understand. But by the second page one’s seeing all sorts of strange glyphs, and I, at least, lose hope of ever being able to decipher what is written in them."` —→ That statement was made by [**Stephen Wolfram**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Wolfram). Are you seriously arguing you can do better than Wolfram?

Comment: I completely maintain that he is being hyperbolic. Even the [wikipedia page for PM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica) has an easy to understand explanation of the symbols and they're all symbols that anyone who has taken a class that covers propositional and predicate logic understand. The [SEP even has an awesome article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/) specifically about the notation in PM, it is not some arcane hieroglyphic ridden tome, it's a standard layout of type theory using outdated symbols.

Comment: If you're telling me that Wolfram is being genuine when he says he can't follow that SEP article then I don't see how we can agree on any of this. And that's fine, I'm just trying to give feedback about how I believe your answer to this question does not actually serve to answer the question and would be better as a comment or at least expanded upon to explain *how* and *why* Russell and Whitehead did what they did.

Comment: @Not_Here : Then why don't you summarize Russel's proof in a way us muggles understand it in an answer of your own instead of wasting both your and my time arguing how much smarter you are than Stephen Wolfram? ;-)

Comment: Sure: There are things called natural numbers, each one has a unique successor, theres a thing called an addition function, it represents a chain of successor functions. 1+1=2 is a valid use of the addition function because 2 is the successor of 1, QED.

Comment: @JohnSlegers, my comment was drawing attention to the horrible visual quality of the screenshot you posted. I'm not saying anything about the difficulty of the work, or claiming that nobody would be able to grasp the concepts conveyed. The particular file you posted is unreadable because it's been horribly compressed and therefore visually degraded so severely that I can only make out about 40% of the characters on the page. Perhaps I need an eye exam. Can you read it?

Comment: @Not_Here : It seems that you are already starting with a lot of assumptions here. It kinda defeats the purpose of trying to prove something as fundamental as 1 + 1 = 2 when you already start off with that many assumptions...

Comment: @jeffreysbrother : I see. I replaced the screenshot with a better quality screenshot! Not that it helps me understand what's on that page, though ;-)

Comment: You must have no idea how formal logic works huh? You asked me to summarize Russell's proof and that is exactly what I did. Obviously the ideas of natural number and successor are defined earlier in the book but you said "summarize their proof" not "summarize the entire book." I don't understand why you're so stuck on claiming ignorance and intellectual inferiority and quote mining Wolfram of all people instead of actually ready the very simple links if you actually want to learn. You realize your appeal to him is a fallacious appeal to authority, right? This answer is useless

Comment: @Not_Here : I work in R&D as a software engineer. I write code for a living. And I loved mathematics in high school. So yes, I do understand how formal logic works. And yes, you do have a point here. Which sources would you recommend that are just detailed enough - but not too much - to help me relieve me of my ignorance on the matter?

Comment: The ones that I sent you before work well, [here's](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/pm54.43.html) a very simple proof using modern symbols, Kleene's *Introduction to Metamathematics*, Gödel's *Russell’s Mathematical Logic*, or Russell's *Mathematical Logic as Based on the Theory of Types*. Kleene's book was the entry level textbook to people studying mathematical logic for almost 40 years and he goes over the ideas in PM in them, if it were true that almost nobody in the world could understand it, it would be incredibly weird that the most prominent textbook has an entire chapter about it.

Answer (score -2):

The principle of Maths is to use them in order to solve logical problems.
In another universe, if you have one apple and I give you another one apple, how many apples will you have? If you will have 3 apples, then 1+1 will be 3, because the people in that universe have been developed an arythmetic system which correspond to their realities and needs.